# Why was ~/.tezos-node not renamed to ~/.octez-node along with the other changes?

Tags: untagged

Octez has changed much of the naming within it from 'tezos' to octez, I am curious why this was not changed or if there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is the "tezos node data directory". As far as I know TezEdge (not developed atm) had a multiple ways of storing the node data. Amongst the options one was compatible with the octez client. I haven't actually tried starting to sync with one client and continue with another but in theory that could work.
But regarding your question I believe it was just forgotten and I recommend to open an issue on the octez GitLab :)

The one reason to not rename would be backwards compatibility after the client upgrade.